# Empty integer array variables are outputting as zeroes, some as empties. So confused

Tags: linux, multidimensional-array, ada

I'm writing an Ada program to solve sudoku puzzles. Right now I'm just trying to get the array to fill and output correctly. I take in a text document like so:

```
4 5 7 89 
  2 5 6  
  79  542
  35 6489
   3 8   
 6847 91 
 238  59 
 79 3 2 1
1  6  7 3
```

where spaces are empty squares. 
The array declaration:

```
Sudoku_Array : array (1..9, 1..9) of Integer;
```

Here's the code for assigning values to the array. Is_Char_Number checks if the character is 0-9, and ConverttoNum converts Char to an integer. The array should just have a null value where spaces are.

```
Open(File, In_File, Argument(1));
while not End_Of_File(File) loop
    for R in 1..9 loop
        for C in 1..9 loop
            Get(File, Char);
            if Is_Char_Number(Char) then
                Sudoku_Array(R,C) := ConverttoNum(Char);
            end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;
end loop;
```

So, if I input the above unfinished sudoku puzzle, I get this out (Put with a width of 2):

```
 4 0 5 0 732630 8 9-1620489328
326304196088 2 0 56846 6 0 0
-161330220832630 7 91163006750 0 5 4 2
32767-1613303064 3 532630 6 4 8 9
 1 1 0 3 1 8-161330306432630 0
 0 6 8 4 7-1613314008 9 1 1
 0 2 3 8-161330220832630 5 9-1623044096
32630 7 94198472 31264732688 2-1615461819 1
 1 0 6 6-162053872032630 732630 3
```

I'm assuming the crazy numbers are null array instances, but some of them are coming out as zeros, as if they're being set as the integer 0.

So, is there a way to properly set an integer array value to null?
And, is there a way to better display the results on the screen? Show a space rather than an insane number.

Thanks

EDIT: Thanks guys, I may have been coming about this the wrong way. Instead of trying to set empty spaces as a null array value, I think I can set it as zero. Because there's no zeroes in a sudoku, They will all have to be changed anyways. Thanks guys! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two easy ways : pick one.

1) Initialise the array :

```
Sudoku_Array : array (1..9, 1..9) of Integer := (others => (others => 0));
```

This may look odd, but `(others => 0)` sets every element in a 1-D array to 0, and the other `others =>` clause does this for every row.

2) add a default action in an `else` clause.

```
if Is_Char_Number(Char) then
   Sudoku_Array(R,C) := ConverttoNum(Char);
else 
   Sudoku_Array(R,C) := 0;
end if;
```

I think the initialisation is neater here, but both ways have their uses.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how Ada works, but you seem to check only if there is a char with

```
if Is_Char_Number(Char) then
      Sudoku_Array(R,C) := ConverttoNum(Char);
end if;
```

So if it is a char convert it and put it in the array, and if not? Then you insert a zero that will do what you want I suppose